# discord - send message to bot from client

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js

The scenario is something like this:

1. User posts something in one of the channel.
2. Bot replies to this user in a DM  with

```
msg.author.send("I am the bot, and sending you this message as DM")
```

3. now, I want user to reply back to this bot in the DM again and i want bot and this user to communicate in the DM.

It seems like I can't achieve the user to send back the message to bot in the same DM.

I am using `discord.js`

Any idea ?

Comment: Send message to bot from client? What does that mean?

Comment: bot replies to user in a dm, and when user sends back the message to the bot in the dm, bot doesn't receive this message, unless user sends a message again in the channel.

Answer (score 0):

to dm a person, you must use `message.author.send("Your message here.")`
but you must have client code.